# What do inductance calculators show?

Tags: pcb

I have come across 'PCB via inductance calculators' online that simply ask for radius, diameter and height of the via to provide an inductance value.

What are they showing? I always thought inductance was due to a current loop and the cross-sectional area formed by that current loop.

How can these calculators provide inductance values with no loop information?

Comment: There is also a concept like a single-wire "self inductance". This scales essentially with length and cross section of a conductor. It is *not accurate* if there are any nearby return conductors. It will *overestimate* inductance, because the loop inductance is more appropriate in such cases.

Comment: Every wire carrying current has a magnetic field around it.

Comment: Search term: partial (self-)inductance.

Answer (score 0):

> *I have come across 'PCB via inductance calculators' online that simply
> ask for radius, diameter and height of the via to provide an
> inductance value.*

and

> *I always thought inductance was due to a current loop and the
> cross-sectional area formed by that current loop.*

A via will be perpendicular to the normal current flow through tracks and hence, the magnetic field it produces is also perpendicular to the magnetic field produced by tracks or loops. In other words they won't interact in the main.

For this reason, it makes sense to think of a via as a small structural item that can have an effective inductance independent to the overall loop.

Comment: However, someone who is actually concerned with the inductance of a via, is likely working on an application where it is good practice or even essential to place return vias as close as possible, or even have checker board patterns of forward and return current vias. In these cases, the via self-inductance given by these calculators is not a very accurate or relevant quantity. (just an addition, not criticizing your answer)